# FileChooser onFocus of text box C++

Tags: visual-c++, mfc, visual-studio-2005, onfocus, filechooser

I want to bypass the need for a button to invoke a FileChooser dialog in my application, so I'm setting it so that when the text box gains focus, the FileChooser just launches automatically.

This is easy to do, but the problem is that after the user selects a file and hits okay, the text box they were on is still in focus, so the FileChooser gets "stuck" and keeps reactivating.

I would just set it to jump to the next control box, but the next few boxes also launch a FileChooser, and I think it will be confusing for the user if the FileChooser *appears* to just stay there...they might think it is stuck.

Is there a way to remove focus from a control?

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: note that auto launching a file chooser might be annoying to users

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of removing focus do this:
Declare a variable for that textbox, like bool opened = false;
Once the file chooser is opened, set it to true, and make sure before you open the file chooser you check if the variable is set to true or false, if it's false, open it, if it's true, leave it

Comment: Ah, this will work. I thought maybe it would work with a flag of some sort. Good idea! Thank you.

Comment: I had to wait for 15 minutes before I could accept one and got sidetracked working on my code. My mistake. I have awarded you the best answer.